# Error message when trying to install from USB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have an old Lenovo laptop which came with Windows 8 preinstalled. I "factory reset" it and installed Ubuntu but then decided I wanted to switch to Zorin instead. I followed [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/) and deleted all non-NTFS partitions (the ones it would let me delete anyway).

I then used  my Lenovo One Recovery software which brought me to a grub rescue terminal where I entered

```
fwsetup
```

That gave me a boot menu and I moved Ubuntu down to the the 3rd spot on that list and  Windows up to the 1st spot. That allowed me to boot into Windows where I created a "system repair disk tool" and followed these steps to supposedly remove the GRUB bootloader:

1. Click the Repair your computer option after booting from the disc.
2. On the Choose an option screen, click the Troubleshoot icon.
3. Click the Advanced options tile, and then click the Command Prompt tile.
4. Once a Command Prompt window is open, type the following command and press Enter to run it: `bootrec.exe/fixmbr`

That seemed to have worked so I rebooted my computer and it booted back into Windows 8. I then tried to install Zorin OS again from my Live USB just as I had with Ubuntu. I got a message saying something along the lines of "You can't boot from a live USB or don't have the option to boot from a Live USB," which I know I do because I did it earlier on the Ubuntu installation! Also when I click on "Use a device" it shows Ubuntu there as a device.

And after that it said everything was successful and to reboot my computer and I did so. I held down my power button to it shutdown and then powered the system back up and it booted back into Windows 8. I then tried to install Zorin OS again from my Live USB the same way I did Ubuntu when I installed it. I got a message saying something along of the lines "You can't boot from a live USB or don't have the option to boot from a Live USB," which I know I do because I did it earlier for the Ubuntu installation! Also when I click on "Use a device" it shows Ubuntu there as a device.

So, what can I do to remove the remains of Ubuntu and to allow me to boot from my Live USB again to boot up and install Zorin OS?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the Lenovo One Key recovery software from within my Windows 8 OS after  entering my UEFI firmware settings and moving the GRUB Boot Loader down the list behind Windows Boot Manager.